# Opening a file of the theme from outside

Tags: permissions, pdf

I have a problem.
I want to open a file that is in the active theme. Actually, I have a link that is shown in an admin menu, and when I click the link I want to redirect to a file that is stored in the theme folder, but I am getting a http 500 error. Is there any chance that the file don't have permission to open from the admin pannel?

The menu in the admin pannel looks like this:
[image]

When I click the pdf icon(at the end of each row in the table), I want to redirect the the file placed as in the photo below:
[image]

The file actually contains code for generating a pdf(with tcpdf plugin).
The value of the href attribute of the link to redirect to the file is :
[image]

After clicking the link, is shown the error below:
[image]

Any idea where can be the problem ?

Comment: I would strongly advise against using a standalone PHP file to handle requests like that for security reasons, but also because it can be very fragile to maintain. It's unnecessary. A HTTP 500 error is just a generic error code, you need to look at your PHP file to get the actual error message

Comment: Also, can you remove the picture of code and replace it with text in a code block?

Comment: 500 is usually not a question of permission but a syntax error. Note that you can't use any WordPress function in a standalone file.

Comment: It was a syntax error, thank you very much!